# Kubernetes context is not set

Tags: kubernetes

I have this config file

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    server: [REDACTED] // IP of my cluster
  name: staging
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: staging
    user: ""
  name: staging-api
current-context: staging-api
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users: []
```

I run this command

```
kubectl config --kubeconfig=kube-config use-context staging-api
```

I get this message

```
Switched to context "staging-api".
```

I then run

```
kubectl get pods
```

and I get this message

```
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

As far as I can tell from the docs

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/

I'm doing it right. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Try the following steps to access the kubernetes cluster. This steps assumes that you have your k8s certificates in /etc/kubernetes.

You need to setup the cluster name, Kubeconfig, User and Kube cert file in following variables and then simply run those commands:

```
CLUSTER_NAME="kubernetes"
KCONFIG=admin.conf
KUSER="kubernetes-admin"
KCERT=admin

cd /etc/kubernetes/

$ kubectl config set-cluster ${CLUSTER_NAME} \
  --certificate-authority=pki/ca.crt \
  --embed-certs=true \
  --server=https://${KUBERNETES_PUBLIC_ADDRESS}:6443 \
  --kubeconfig=${KCONFIG}

$ kubectl config set-credentials kubernetes-admin \
  --client-certificate=admin.crt \
  --client-key=admin.key \
  --embed-certs=true \
  --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf

$ kubectl config set-context ${KUSER}@${CLUSTER_NAME} \
  --cluster=${CLUSTER_NAME} \
  --user=${KUSER} \
  --kubeconfig=${KCONFIG}

$ kubectl config use-context ${KUSER}@${CLUSTER_NAME} --kubeconfig=${KCONFIG}
$ kubectl config view --kubeconfig=${KCONFIG}
```

After this you will be able to access the cluster. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You need to fetch the credentials of the running cluster. Try this:

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials <cluster_name> --zone <zone_name>
```

More info:

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/get-credentials

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same problem like mentioned in the title.

When I executed:

```
 kubectl config current-context
```

The output was:

```
error: current-context is not set
```

And in my case it was indentation problem.
One white-space before `current-context` caused me a few hours of debugging:

```
contexts:
- context:
   cluster: arn:aws:eks:us-east-2:...:cluster/...
   user: arn:aws:eks:us-east-2:...:cluster/...
 name: arn:aws:eks:us-east-2:...:cluster/...
current-context: arn:aws:eks:us-east-2:...:cluster/... <-Whitespace at the begging of the row was the source of the error.
```

Comment: Which file had incorrect indentation? Was it `~/.kube/config`?

Comment: @Marc, I beleive so.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on a mac m1...

The problem was that i am using **kubectx** and **kubens**, so that tools are ones that are controlling context and namespace.
In this situation The correct command has to be

```bash
kubectx staging-api
```

More information on the [Official Repository](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx)